# What type of code is being stored in microcontroller RAM section?

Tags: microcontroller, memory

The program memory layout looks like this:

[image]

But in every embedded forum it is said that:
`Code is being stored in flash memory, RAM memory is for data`

Therefore, what is being stored in text section of RAM memory? Is it same code as in flash?

Comment: When you write "the program memory layout", you're saying you know that's the layout for your program, right? Otherwise, please edit your question and explain where you got that from and why you're trying to compare it to something else. It reads like you just want free personal tutorial on information that's readily and plentifully available on the internet, as with many of your questions.

Comment: Usually code is stored in flash on common MCU's. But many compilers allow for placing executable code in RAM for faster execution. It is then copied from flash into RAM on startup. Check this out for example: https://mcu-things.com/blog/ramfunc-gcc/

Comment: There's systems that load the program from non-volatile storage  to RAM before executing from RAM. On such systems both program and data sit in RAM during execution. Your image is based on such a system. Other systems, such as many microcontrollers, have separate program memory (flash memory for example) and RAM. Obviously the memory layout looks diffirent on those systems.

Comment: Your diagram is probably confusing you more than it's helping - it's likely referring to a computer's memory and not a microcontroller. All those memory sections are not all always present, nor are they necessarily placed in that order. In well-designed microcontroller firmware, the firmware engineer is responsible for allocating various memory blocks for whichever sections are actually needed by the application. Typically `.text` would be in Flash, while `.data`, `.bss`, the one or more stacks, and the heap (if used) would be in RAM.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, I thought that this layout which I was referring to is something like general in all MCUs. Now I know it is not.

Comment: @TonyM Well, people here think that's I'm too lazy to use google. The truth is that most of articles are being simply confusing for me. And moreover some information are new for me, such new that I don't know what should I even search for to get this information. That's why I'm asking for it on stack exchange . . .

Comment: @yeuop, I see yours as the complete opposite. We were starters and learners once too and I'd say most remember well the hard work of learning it all. Many of us did this pre-internet so we had to forage for the information. I designed for factory mass production from young (20) and it had to right first time for manufacture or there were big costs. No 'hey just respin' attitude (respin was a criminal word), that writes off expensive stock. I was guided, but not led, by the few experienced engineers so I scoured datasheets and racked my brains to deduce and understand all this stuff. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) The things you learn most deeply and profitably from are the major problems that he had to understand and fight your way through. Telling someone the answer don't give that. That was me and many here too, I'm sure. Meanwhile, there's now the internet and the untold acres and acres of information *to deduce from and understand from and learn from* (not the answers to be handed out) that's sitting there, a second away. The speed at which one could learn from basics up, like we did. I wasn't taught most of this stuff - I dug it out. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) So if we had the answer to each of the 'one line question, hundred line answer please' questions that come up on this site, it would be a sad, tragic day for the future of solid quality engineering if we posted them. I really hope you can see that because, professional or amateur, it's one of the most important lessons you learn. As it was for us. Knowledge is not 'owned', it doesn't belong to someone, there's no hierarchy of important and lesser engineers. Other people gave it to us and we pass it on to more, like a relay baton. But knowledge must be toiled for else it's not learned.

Comment: Incidentally, I know the answer to this question - because a younger me sat there, night after night, in my non-work time, reading up on software programming, OS architecture and goodness-know-what-else out of self-discipline and hungry interest. No-one taught me in a classroom, no-one made me learn it. Many people helped in small ways. That's the only reason I know it. From the basics right up, from assembler into HLL programming and more learning. Been solid gold, professionally. The books cost loads. Internet costs nothing. Dig in - it's the best present you'll ever give yourself :-)

Comment: @TonyM This speech was the most educational thing I have ever got here... Now I see the difference and how proper approach should look like... Thank you :)

Comment: Great, glad it helped, despite its typos' :-) Am not overstating to say it's paramount. And a correction to it: I was indeed led by very experienced engineers and lots of other people in a ton of ways, with huge investment of their time. I was trying to summarise that they didn't hand out answers, the times I got "You work it out - if I just tell you, you won't learn anything". I was trying to convey that with "not led by" but it instead reads, to me, as badly dismissing their huge contributions to my engineering and professional education. Anyway, very glad it makes sense and clarifies it :-D

Answer (score 1):

Whilst 'most' microcontrollers execute code from internal flash, it is not a given. There's plenty of microcontrollers that do not have internal flash and instead have an external flash chip.

Some may execute code from this external flash (called XIP execute in place) or they might copy some or all of the code into ram for execution. So you need to be very clear about the exact microcontroller you are referring to.

The memory layout diagram you show is for a microcontroller that has code in ram. The comments say 'read from program file by exec' - that hardly sounds like a microcontroller with internal flash.

Answer (score -4):

Not entirely sure what "Text" would mean, unless it is literally alphanumeric stuff. However, it is a common practice to copy code from flash into RAM because it can be executed faster from RAM

Comment: The "text" section is where executable code lies. It has nothing to do with alphanumeric data.

Comment: Also please note that the image provided may not apply to microcontrollers which have code in the flash, the image may be about programs running on PC under some OS.